# Azure Website Connection to a ServiceBus Queue remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, servicebus

I have a simple Azure website (PaaS website) that is trying to connect to a Service Bus queue.  However, it is getting the error:

> [WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'XXXXXXXXX-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net']
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>   +6543605    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13    Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenCore(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout, String& expiresIn,
>   String& audience) +617

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?  It's looking like a permissions issue, but I'm new to Azure and I'm not seeing how to fix it.  It's using the service busses "RootManageSharedAccessKey" that has Manage, Send, and Listen permissions.

I also have a worker role setup that is able to access the queue, so I know the queue is there.  I can also use Visual Studio to send a test message to the queue and it is received by the worker.  I just can't get the front end azure website to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed how I was connecting to the service bus.  The problem was related to not passing in the correct values to the NamespaceManager.  I ended up using the following to connect to the Service bus:

```
    // By default when connecting to the queue we will look at the appSettings for they key "Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"
    //
    //  <appSettings>
    //    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    //  </appSettings>
    //
    public TachyonQueueClient(String queueName, String appSettingKey = "Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString")
    {
        name = queueName;

        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(appSettingKey);
        namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueName);
        }

        // Initialize the connection to Service Bus Queue
        client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a new service bus namespace from azure portal recently? There has been a change made where the default authentication mechanism is SAS and no ACS namespaces are provisioned automatically.

Please refer to this blog which has details on this issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servicebus/archive/2014/09/03/change-to-azure-service-bus-portal-default-authentication-mechanism-for-service-bus-namespaces-now-sas.aspx

Comment: I created the Namespace in the old portal.  I can connect to the queue in the worker role to pull messages off it, but I get the above error when I try to access it from an Azure website.

Comment: It could definitely be related to the link you supplied, I will look into it more.

Comment: I ended up changing how I connect to the Service bus.